# Navigate back to parent URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm trying to navigate back to parent URL when an option is changed and there are more route params and keep the current URL if there are no route params.

I will give you an example to make all more clear.

So, I have 3 components: **CompA**, **CompB** and **CompC** which holds a list of items and when I navigate to one of this I keep in URL:

**/compA**, **/compB** or **/compC**.

Navigate inside of each component to an item is possible and also kept in URL as **/compA/item1**.

I have a drop-down to select a specific **client** and what I want is to navigate back to parent when the client was changed and I have route params or to keep the specific route if don't.

For example, I'm on **/compA/item2** and I change the client. The expected behaviour is to navigate to **/compA**. Or, If I'm on **/compB** and I change the client I should remain on **/compB**.

I found a solution using this

```
this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute.parent });
```

but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using:

```
const parentURL = this.router.url.split('/')[1];
this.router.navigate([parentURL]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `.` is "current directory", `../` is "one level up"

```
this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute.parent });
```